# How to find X value so that the slope of the function is -1 (exponents)?

Tags: derivatives, exponential-function, approximation, slope

I was watching [3Blue1Brown](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCYO_jab_esuFRV4b17AJtAw) playlist of derivatives and integrals, after learning and understanding the visualization of those topics, I wanted to play around with the math.

**Introduction to the problem**

This problem seems very easy, but after a lot of trying I just couldn't get the result, I talked to my colleagues and they couldn't work out a solution, I tried to talk and solve with math students but things didn't flow smoothly.

So what is my problem? I took some equation and I wanted to find for which value X, the slope is -1?

**We need to do the following things:**

1. Calculate the derivative of the function.
2. Compare the derivative of the function to the slope we want to find, which is -1.
3. Check what value of X satisfies the equation.

---

Original function: $f(x) = e^{x^2}$

Derivative function: $f'(x) = 2xe^{x^2}$

Compare derivative function to the slope: $2xe^{x^2} = -1$

---

**Attempt *1* to solve the problem**

At this moment things start to be complicated, how do I manage to find X?
So far I tried to use log rules and play with it to get X, but nothing worked, for example:

$2xe^{x^2} = -1$

$xe^{x^2} = -1/2$

$ln(xe^{x^2}) = ln(-1/2)$

The problem here is that $ln(-1/2)$ is not defined, so this method is not good.

---

**Attempt *2* to solve the problem**

Another approach that I a friend suggested me to do is to use "Euler's formula", which says $e^{ix} = cos(x)+isin(x)$, and then maybe do something with the complex number at the power of $e$ and get a result, but I can't see what I can tweak in this formula to fit it to my problem.

So this method is not good too.

---

**Some visualizations about the problem**

So I decided to go to desmos graphs and see how those functions look like to get an understanding of what I need to do.

This is the graph of $f(x) = e^{x^2}$

[Original graph image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8rME.png)

This is the derivative graph of $f'(x) = 2xe^{x^2}$

[Derivative graph image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9BP0.png)

And this is how the graph looks like with the original graph ($f(x) = e^{x^2}$) and the derivative graph ($f'(x) = 2xe^{x^2}$), at this image I use Wolfram to figure out what is the X point to get the result.

[All together](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSInb.png)

---

**What Wolfram says**

As you can see when I use Wolfram to calculate it for me, Wolfram got an approximate number for variable X which is **x=-0.41936**, but there are no steps how he calculated it.

---

**More thoughts**

so I thought maybe I can use Taylor Series here, but then I remembered that I can use Taylor Series to approximate the value around some value X, how can I apply this for getting the X for requested slope which is -1?

Maybe this approach is also wrong, that's why I am here and asking you guys, how to know at what X number the slope of the function is -1?

Thank you very much!

Comment: There is no way to find that $x$, other than to find numerical approximations to it. One way to do this is called *Newton's Method*. This may be how Wolfram does it.

Comment: So, have you had a look at Newton's Method?

Comment: Are you still here?

Comment: Hey there [GerryMyerson](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/8269/gerry-myerson), sorry for the delay I was in flights in the recent days!

I started calculating with Newton's Method and it worked great!
I will write a response now for my question using Newton's Method 
for future people who will see this post, and I will mention you there for the help, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Eventually, I understood how to solve this problem by [Gerry Myerson](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/8269/gerry-myerson) help, Gerry suggested using Newton's Method and it worked perfectly.
I will provide the results of this method so future people who see this post will see the results also.

Thank you very much, Gerry Myerson!

This is [Wikipedia explanation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) for Newton's Method, as you can see there we need to get the result by step by step calculations.

$Xn+1 = Xn - f(Xn)/f'(Xn)$

When we try to get the approximate value for our equation, the equation is the derivative of the first equation, so we will work with the equation $f(x) = 2xe^{x^2} + 1 = 0$

So at some point we need to calculate the derivative of the equation $f(x) = 2xe^{x^2} + 1 = 0$, therefore let's calculate it now and it will be $f'(x) = e^{x^2}(2+4x^2)$.

All we need to do now is to plug in the numbers a few times and we get approximate of the result we need.

$X0 = 1$.

$X1 = 1 - f(1)/f'(1) = 0.6054$

$X2 = 0.6054 - f(0.6054)/f'(0.6054) = 0.0560$

$X3 = ...$

$X4 = ...$

$X5 = ...$

$X6 = -0.4194 - f(-0.4194)/f'(-0.4194) = -0.4194$

As you can see from my question the approximate number is **x=-0.41936**, and from Newton Method, we got the same approximation **x=-0.4194**.

Thanks again for Gerry Myerson for the help and there we have the solution :)